# How to change validation MVC to lost focus on field?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using a modelclass with data anotations in MVC 4 to validate a form in my view. This works fine, however, the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bijkomendeUitleg)` shows my errors while typing...

For example I have a minimum length of 10 for a text field, when I start typing and I have less then 10 characters, the error shows up.

I want errors to show up when I lose focus on the textfield or when clicked on submit...

Is there any way to alter this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

try this If you are using jquery 1.7.1 with unobtrusive validation, something like this should do the trick:

```
<script>
    $('input[data-val=true]').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

If using an older version of jquery, change to this:

```
<script>
    $('input[data-val=true]').blur(function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

Comment: I do not know what JQuery MVC uses, as i said the validation was done automaticly, my view does have this
`@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`

Answer (score 0):

Go to jquery.validate.js. There you will find:

```
$.extend($.validator, {......})
```

In it you find:

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
    if ( element.name in this.submitted || element == this.lastElement ) {
        this.element(element);
    }
},
```

Remove this code. I did not try this. But hope it will work for you.